# Selenium и headless режим

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xmlparser

Selenium в PyCharm не работает в headless режиме и переходит сразу в ошибку TimeoutException.
Драйвер для Chrome актуален и подключен...
Когда режим headless отключен, то весь код отрабатывает как надо.

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

*Во-первых, в вашем вопросе не хватает конкретики, приведите пожалуйста хоть какой-нибудь код, воспроизводящий ошибку*

На основе вашего вопроса (в котором не хватает конкретики) могу предложить решение, которое иногда срабатывает.

попробуйте добавить в параметры открытия chrome пункт, задающий размер окна, используя chrome options:

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(EXE_PATH_AND_ETC, options=options)
```

Если это не поможет, попробуйте так же отключить gpu ускорение:

```py
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
```

Comment: спасибо это кажется помогло